# Installation action duplicates source tree to install location during file extraction

Tags: install4j

At the beginning of the Install4J installation action, it extracts all the files in the Distribution Tree to the install location where the user specifies the program should be installed (I don't want that happening as there are only certain files that need to get placed there). Later when I call either of the actions "Move Files/Directories" or "Copy Files/Directories", the files do not get moved or copied. In each of the actions, I specify that the files should be moved to the directory specified by the user, but nothing happens.

I have looked at the install4j admin guide, through other posts here (on StackOverflow), and many pages of Google and I haven't been able to find anything on this subject. I have also created a debug installer to see if anything is amiss and it has not helped. Please note that this installation is for Windows OS only.

When I execute the installer, I want it to only copy the files from the distribution tree that are specified in each "copy" or "move" action within the installation to the appropriate location on the target file-system. Not just extract the entirety of the source file tree to the user-specified "install directory".

Answer (score 0):

The "Install files" action installs files that are in selected file sets and installation components.

You can programmatically change the selection state of [file sets and installation components](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/#install4j.helptopics.concepts.files). For example

```
context.getFileSetById("123").setSelected(false);
```

or

```
context.getInstallationComponentById("123").setSelected(false);
```

> When I execute the installer, I want it to only copy the files from the distribution 
>   tree that are specified in each "copy" or "move" action within the installation to the 
>   appropriate location on the target file-system.

No, it does not work that way, those actions operate on existing files.